# I want to split the sentences into each words

Tags: android, replace, split

I want to split the sentences. I input in the `AutocompleteTextview`, but I can't get the desire output:
example :

```
The fox jump over the bridge
```

desire output :

```
The* fox* jump* over* the* bridge*
```

This my code:

```
 check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String sentences = autocompletetxt.getText().toString();
            String[] splitwords = sentences.split(" ");
            for (String biyak : splitwords)
            {
                textviewdisplaygrammar.setText(biyak + "*");
            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you reassign text value in your for loop. Try like this:

```
String foo = "";    
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     final String sentences = autocompletetxt.getText().toString();
     String[] splitwords = sentences.split(" ");
      for (String biyak : splitwords) {
           foo = foo + biyak + "* ";         
         }
      textviewdisplaygrammar.setText(foo);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

One single instruction is all what you need:

```
sentences.replaceAll(" ", "* ") + "*";
```

No loops, no nothing. Very fast.